# Unable to retrieve rows in sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to select books which have chapter 29 and books which have chapter 30 and so on. I tried the code below but it only returns books that have chapter 29 but not 30, 31, 32

```
SELECT distinct book FROM `bible_kjv` WHERE chapter in (29,30,31,32,33,34,35);
```

Please how can I rewrite code

Comment: do you mean the book should have all the chapters 29,30,31,32?

Comment: no i mean it should select the books separately, books may have chapter 29 but not 30. I want to select all books that have at least one of the chapters

Comment: or do I have to write separate sql statement for each of the chapters. i.e sql for chapter 29, another for 30 and so on

Comment: Your query looks perfectly fine to me. What's the issue? can you post sample data?

Comment: ok i will get that

Comment: The query looks right, check your field types to make sure you don't need ("29","30"...) instead of numeric??   If it's truly numeric then you can just say chapter >= 29  or "chapter between" if range is like your example.

Comment: If you do a Distinct and Genesis is returned, you have already satisfied it.  It has more than 29 and is returned.  You want between or greater than.

Answer (score 3):

The code seems to be fine. Could it be a problem with data **types**? What type is the column 'chapter' set to?

Comment: Yeah you re right. the code is fine. I was using the wrong data so I wasnt getting results as expected

Answer (score 1):

If you do a `Distinct` and Genesis is returned, you have already satisfied the query conditions. Genesis has more than 29 and is returned. When you hit 30, you've already returned Genesis, so you only see it once.  You want between or greater than.

```
SELECT b.book FROM Bible b WHERE chapter >= 29;
```

I'm not sure what you need to accomplish other than that or what you envision it looking like.  Also see Chris Caviness comment.

EDIT:

SELECT b.book FROM Bible b WHERE chapter [BETWEEN](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/between.php) 29 AND 35;

Comment: All I could think of was that giant eared freak from Star Trek III, "Genesis!"

Comment: yeah this code too should work, but I just want between 29 and 35 and not greater

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that this:

```
SELECT distinct book FROM `bible_kjv` WHERE chapter in (29,30,31,32,33,34,35);
```

Is different from this:

```
SELECT distinct book FROM `bible_kjv` WHERE chapter in ('29,30,31,32,33,34,35');
```

The first compares chapter to seven integer values. The second compares chapter to a single string, and since chapter is probably an integer, it casts the string to a numeric value. In MySQL, the numeric value of '29,30,31,32,33,34,35' is 29 (it reads the leading digits, and ignores everything past the comma).

I suspect there's more about your code that you didn't share in the question.

I would guess that you tried to use a parameterized query and passed a single string with your list of chapters. This isn't how parameters work. One parameter can take the place of a single scalar value only, not a list of values.

If you want to use parameters, you'll have to use seven parameter placeholders.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I've noted this, I pass an array of values with `implode(',', $arr) `

Comment: Okay, but the result of implode() is a string. You haven't shown how you combine this value with the SQL query. If you are using a parameterized query, and you pass a single string, it will be like my second example above, like you put quotes around a string of numbers. Only the first number will be used.

Answer (score 0):

you will get record between 29 to 35 then use this query

```
SELECT b.book FROM Bible b WHERE chapter between 29 to 35;
```

and if you want record outside of 29 to 35 then use

```
SELECT b.book FROM Bible b WHERE chapter not between 29 to 35;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT book FROM Bible WHERE chapter BETWEEN 29 AND 35;
```