# GROUP_CONCAT issue with string

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(companyName)FROM company WHERE id IN (27,38)) AS companyName, t.* 
FROM Test t
```

it return output like this,

```
>Apple, Sony
```

But if I pass the id as full string,

```
SELECT (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(companyName) 
        FROM company WHERE id IN ("27,38")) AS companyName, t.* 
FROM Test t
```

So it return first company name only, so output like this

```
>Apple
```

I want to retrieve the data like this Apple, Sony.(Like first query), How can I achieve this one?

Sample Table Structure below

company Table

```
    --------------------
    ID      companyName
    -------------------
    27         Apple
    28         Sony
    .         .
    .         .
```

Comment: could you post the sample data ?

Comment: I think you are leaving out some detail about how you run the query. Are you trying to pass the `27,38` string as a parameter to a single placeholder?  See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/41290896/20860

Comment: My actcual QUERY IS 

SELECT (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(companyName SEPARATOR ',') FROM company WHERE id IN (t.companyIds)) AS companyName, t.* FROM Trailers t 

IN companyIds FIELDS HAVING 27,38,35 LIKE that

Comment: I see your table structure for table test which stores company associations as a coma separated list of ids `27,38` which is an example of bad design

Comment: @ M Khalid Junaid
Can you please suggest some table structure for that

Comment: @Cross i have updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing 27 and 28 as single string so MySQL consider the first number which is 27, that's why it's returning apple. If you want return Apple and Sony you have to split the string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
SELECT group_concat(companyName separator ',')
FROM company WHERE id IN ("27,38");
```

Comment: it RETURN FIRST company NAME Only

Comment: @Cross You need to provide more sample data and expected output clearly

Answer (score 0):

I saw your comments it looks like you are storing company ids for Trailers as a comma separated string which is against of [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), Instead you can add new junction table which hold the reference of both tables company and trailers like

```
trailer
=======
id name
1  some name 


company
id      name
-------------------
1         Apple
2         Sony

trailer_companies (junction table)
trailer_id company_id
---------------------
1          27
1          38
```

Now you can query records by using joins

```
select t.*,group_concat(c.name) companyName
from trailer t
join trailer_companies tc on (t.id = tc.trailer_id)
join company c on (tc.company_id = c.id)
group by t.id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/692610/1)

If you want to continue with your current design which is strongly not advisable because it will be hard to optimize and not fit for scaled apps

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(companyName SEPARATOR ',') 
    FROM company 
    WHERE  FIND_IN_SET(id,t.companyIds) > 0
    ) AS companyName, t.* 
FROM Trailers t
```

Comment: it RETURN FIRST company NAME Only

Comment: You want both company names ? or only first one ?

Comment: Both company name